# Is it possible to calculate efforts of a User across the multiple projects in TFS 2018.3 and Azure DevOps Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are trying to calculate efforts of a User across different projects in the same collection of TFS 2018.3 and Azure DevOps Server (ADS). Is there any possible way to achieve this scenario in TFS/ADS and do we have any official extension from Microsoft or third-party extensions to calculate this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a build-in way to sum up the effort or story points across projects.

[Support for calculated fields and roll-ups](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365423/support-calculated-fields-in-tfs.html) which is still a user voice at present.

As an alternative, you could implement a server side plugin for TFS or create a Web Service that subscribe to TFS Events, then in your code you will use TFS API for the Client Object Model (Work Item Tracking) to get the needed work-items and user info, calculate and save the data to somewhere.

Another solutions is an 3rd-party [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/) extension for Team Foundation Server (TFS)  that enables running custom script when Work Items change, allowing dynamic calculation of field values in TFS and more.

Besides you could also export the query to Excel, and sum the completed work column in Excel.

[image]

All above is for a single project, you need to count them for multiple projects finally.